# Form inputs should clear only with correct submit

Tags: reactjs, redux

My form component looks like :

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            startDate: '',
            endDate: '',
            description: '',
            profileId: this.props.profileId
        }

        this.onStartDateChange = this.onStartDateChange.bind(this);
        this.onEndDateChange = this.onEndDateChange.bind(this);
        this.onDescriptionChange = this.onDescriptionChange.bind(this);
        this.clickHandle = this.clickHandle.bind(this);

    }

 onStartDateChange(event) {
        const startDate = event.target.value
        this.setState({
            startDate: startDate
        })
    }

    onEndDateChange(event) {
        const endDate = event.target.value
        this.setState({
            endDate: endDate
        })
    }

    onDescriptionChange(event) {
        const description = event.target.value
        this.setState({
            description: description
        })
    }

    clickHandle = () => {
        const inputValues = {
            startDate: this.state.startDate,
            endDate: this.state.endDate,
            description: this.state.description
        }
        this.props.onAddClick(this.state.profileId, inputValues);
    }


    render() {

        return (
   <Form>
        <div className={"m-3 form-row"}>
                            <Field type={"date"} className={"form-control col-md-2 mr-2"}
                                   onChange={evt => this.onStartDateChange(evt)}
                                   value={this.state.startDate}
                                   name={"add-start-date"}/>
                            <Field type={"date"} className={"form-control col-md-2 mr-2"}
                                   onChange={evt => this.onEndDateChange(evt)}
                                   value={this.state.endDate}
                                   name={"add-end-date"}/>
                            <Field className={"form-control col-md-2 mr-2"}
                                   type={"textarea"}
                                   onChange={evt => this.onDescriptionChange(evt)}
                                   value={this.state.description}
                                   name={"add-description"}/>
                            <button className="btn btn-info round-btn" href="#"
                                    onClick={this.clickHandle}
                                    type={"button"}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus}/></button>
                        </div>
             </Form>
}
```

My action looks like:

```
export const onAddClick = (profileId, educationData = {
    startDate: '',
    endDate: '',
    description: ''
}) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        const education = {
            startDate: educationData.startDate,
            endDate: educationData.endDate,
            description: educationData.description
        };

            return axios.post(`${ENTRY_API_URL}`)
            .then(response => {
                dispatch(_addEducation(profileId, response.data))
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                if (error) {
                    dispatch(_requestFailure(profileId, error.response.data))
                }
            })
    };
};
```

My store looks like

```
workExperience: [
          {
            id: '5d6e3368993694389c903c50',
            startDate: '2019-09-04',
            endDate: '2019-09-12',
            description: 'description'
          },
```

How can I clear input only when request to API is correct and when its wrong leave it. Can I make it without redux-forms ?  I tried with some flag in store but it change slowly after I clicked the button. Should I try make  some state in redux for this form ?

Comment: Where are you calling addEducation? Why did you include that code if you aren't using it? is that onAddClick?

Comment: Yes its onAddClick , sorry I changed it

Comment: And what is the redux state being changed by addEducation?